# How to tune the model in order to get higher accuracy rate?

Tags: orange

Hi I am working with Orange.
I use Random Forest to make regression predictions. However, only around 40% of accuracy in my model. How can I tune my model?

Can I adjust each feature weighting before training the model? If yes, how can I do that? If no, any idea to increase the %?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Orange interface allows you to adjust the number of trees (you should definitely change this from 10), the number of attributes considered at each split, and the growth of the trees:
[image]

If you want greater control over the creation of the trees I would suggest using Scikit-learn: http://scikit-learn.org/